# Edit site pages through model fields from Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is there  way to edit website pages (About, Services, Contact etc.) in Django Admin via fields defined in the model.py? For example in WP I would have a set of custom fields using the ACF plugin, called 'about_image' and 'about_text', these would then output into the required page template.

image field.

```
<?php $image = get_field('about_image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

text field.

```
<h2><?php the_field('about_text'); ?></h2>
```

These fields are then editable via the Admin under each page, About, Services etc. Super easy for the client to edit content...

If this is beyond the scope of Django, thats ok I will try Django-CMS but I just love the simplicity of pure Django. If this has been answered before, I apologise, I did spent some time searching for solutions...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [django flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/flatpages/).

> Django comes with an optional “flatpages” application. It lets you
>   store simple “flat” HTML content in a database and handles the
>   management for you via Django’s admin interface and a Python API.
>
> A flatpage is a simple object with a URL, title and content. Use it
>   for one-off, special-case pages, such as “About” or “Privacy Policy”
>   pages, that you want to store in a database but for which you don’t
>   want to develop a custom Django application.

It's not exactly as powerful as wordpress, but django isn't horrible bloatware like wordpress either.

Comment: Hey cheers for your response! I have tested Django flatpages on Django docs and its pretty good for what it is but I was hoping for something a bit more flexible with the ability to add multiple custom fields per page. I will mark as the answer anyway, thanks. I agree WP is pretty bloated but it does get the job done!

Comment: Well I did say it's not as powerfull as wordpress but it works for most purposes. But it's so easy to write your own CMS/Blog with django that most django newbies do it as a learning excercise

Comment: I've seen some pretty impressive websites done with Django, including this one - http://athfieldarchitects.co.nz/. Would love to know how they did it! I agree Django seems pretty easy to get a CMS and Blog up quickly, its nice getting stuck in code wise with the MVT rather than having everything hidden in WP core or plugins.